# What does (,li) mean in Vim Latex

Tags: editors, vim

I am using Macvim together with Vim-Latex suite. On the Vim Latex webpage they list Environment macros as follows:

```
ELI (,li)------------- list
EDE (,de)------------- description
```

etc. What does (for example) `,li` mean in this context?. How do I use this key combination to put a list in my `.tex` file. I am assuming `,li` means hit the local leader key and then hit `li` in normal mode. But I have remapped the leader key in vim to `,`.

Can anybody shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `,li` is the list of three keys that will work in visual mode (e.g., you have some text selected). For example pressing `,li` will surround selected text with `\begin{list} \end{list}`. I think `leader` is independent of that. The details can be found in section `3.1.2.2` of the  [Latex-Suite manual](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/environment-mappings.html#enclosing-env-threeletter).

Comment: This clears it up. I thought it was to be used in the normal mode. Explains why it didn't work :).